# Remove first element within every li

Tags: html, jquery

I want to remove the first element within every li element
but my code only removes the a element from the first li and not all li

example below.

I have this

```
<ul class="myclass">
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#"></a> <---Remove this element
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#"></a> <---Remove this element
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#"></a> <---Remove this element
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>

jQuery("li.product-category>a").first().remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this using `each()`:

```js
$("li.product-category").each(function() {
  $(this).find("a").first().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myclass">
 <li class="product-category product">
 <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#"></a> 
   <a href="">all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop will make it work.

```js
jQuery("li.product-category").each(function(){
    $(this).find("a").first().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myclass">
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#">aac</a> <---Remove this element
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#">aad</a> <---Remove this element
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#">eaa</a> <---Remove this element
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.product')
for (let item of list){
item.children[0].remove()
}
```

```html
<ul class="myclass">
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#">del</a>
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#">del</a>
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="product-category product">
  <a href="#">del</a> 
  <a href="">
   all product info here
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```